# How to pass temporary data from filter to output in logstash

Tags: logstash

How do you pass temporary data from a filter to output in logstash?

```
filter {    

    mutate {
         add_field => {"TEMP_DATA" => "%{some value}"}
    }      
}

output {  
   elasticsearch {
       document_id => "%{TEMPDATA}"
   }
}
```

The above will output the TEMPDATA value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct and standard way of achieving this is by using the [`@metadata` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata). `@metadata` is a special field that will never be stored in your events but whose sole purpose is to pass data among your inputs, filters and outputs.

Sample usage:

```
filter {
  mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][TEMP_DATA]" => "%{some value}" } }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][TEMP_DATA]}"
  }
}
```